# Spring @Value property doesn't read nested YAML properties correctly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have a simple YAML property policy.statement that I want to read from a configuration java file using @PropertySource and @Value annotations. If I use only @Value(${statement}) it reads ok, but if I use @Value(${policy.statement}) if can't find. And at the YAML file I use policy: [enter] statement: value . Why doesn't @Value work if I use ${property1.property2} but only if I use ${property2} alone ? It doesn't make sense. Print and source link attached.[image]

full project at the "doubt" branch at the project link:
https://github.com/danielpm1982/springboot2-health-record/tree/doubt

Comment: * sorry, the title should be:

Spring @Value annotation doesn't read nested YAML properties correctly

Comment: see here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings `YAML files cannot be loaded by using the @PropertySource annotation`

Comment: So how should I use specific yaml files properties at the configuration files ? If not using PropertySource ? Only by using it at the standard application.yaml ? Not with custom names ?

Comment: You can .properies file if you want with custom name @DanielPinheiro

Comment: Ok, with .properties it works fine. I just thought to learn another way by using yaml, but I guess Spring must evolve first regarding this particular incompatibility. Thanks ! 

Comment: There are way using yml files also, just explore google and you will find sonething in stackoverflow @DanielPinheiro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SOLVED]
You can't use PropertySource or PropertySources Spring Annotation with custom named yaml files... only with .properties txt files. So, to solve the problem, instead of using custom named .yaml files I had to use the default named application.yaml. This way there's no need to use PropertySource for the .yaml file (only for the .properties ones) and it all worked fine, including the different profile selection of my yaml file properties according to the profile set at the application.properties .

Thanks to Deadpool:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/9959152/deadpool

Full project available at the master branch of the project link:
https://github.com/danielpm1982/springboot2-health-record